# How to feed a list as an input to a groupby function in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, analytics

Suppose a subset of a dataset comprises these 2 columns,

```
     attacker_king              attacker_commander
0   Joffrey/Tommen Baratheon    Jaime Lannister
1   Joffrey/Tommen Baratheon    Gregor Clegane
2   Joffrey/Tommen Baratheon    Jaime Lannister, Andros Brax
3   Robb Stark                  Roose Bolton, Wylis Manderly, Medger Cerwyn
4   Robb Stark                  Robb Stark, Brynden Tully
5   Robb Stark                  Robb Stark, Tytos Blackwood, Brynden Tully
```

My objective is to get the 'set of commanders' that each king deploys, as per the dataset.

```
[x for x in battles['attacker_commander'].dropna().str.split(',').sum()]
```

The above command obtains only comma separated list of commanders
But if I choose to use the following list comprehension,

```
battles[['attacker_commander','attacker_king']].groupby('attacker_king').sum()
```

I get an output where

```
attacker_king                      attacker_commander   
Balon/Euron Greyjoy         Victarion GreyjoyAsha GreyjoyTheon GreyjoyTheo...
Joffrey/Tommen Baratheon    Jaime LannisterGregor CleganeJaime Lannister, ...
Robb Stark                  Roose Bolton, Wylis Manderly, Medger Cerwyn, H...
Stannis Baratheon           Stannis Baratheon, Davos SeaworthStannis Barat...
```

The problem with this approach is, suppose a row has just 1 commander ,when that is summed with next row, output can look like 'Victarion GreyjoyAsha Greyjoy' instead of 'Victarion Greyjoy,Asha Greyjoy'. So does it make sense to use the list created using

```
[x for x in battles['attacker_commander'].dropna().str.split(',').sum()]
```

and feed it to a groupby('attacker_king') or what approach do you folks suggest?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need `apply` with function `join` first:

```
battles.groupby('attacker_king')['attacker_commander'].apply(','.join)
```

If need remove `NaN`:

```
battles.groupby('attacker_king')['attacker_commander'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()))
```

Then `split` and use `set` for unique values:

```
df = battles.groupby('attacker_king')['attacker_commander']
            .apply(lambda x: list(set(','.join(x.dropna()).split(','))))
print (df)
```

The best solution for debugging is use custom function and then rewrite code to `lambda`:

```
def f(x):
    #Series by attacker_commander per group
    print (x)
    #first remove NaN
    print (x.dropna())
    #join by ,
    print (','.join(x.dropna()))
    #create list by split
    print (','.join(x.dropna()).split(','))
    #convert to set - unique values
    print (set(','.join(x.dropna()).split(',')))
    #set convert to list
    print (list(set(','.join(x.dropna()).split(','))))
    return list(set(','.join(x.dropna()).split(',')))

df = battles.groupby('attacker_king')['attacker_commander'].apply(f)
print (df)
```

---

But also one posssible solution is remove rows with `NaN` by column [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) first:

```
def f(x):
    return list(set(','.join(x).split(',')))

df = battles.dropna(subset=['attacker_commander']).groupby('attacker_king')['attacker_commander'].apply(f)
print (df)
```

Comment: In case the subset contains certain 'nans', how does `battles.groupby('attacker_king')['attacker_commander'].apply(','.join)` incorporate the dropna() method because I tried adding it just before 'apply' method and it results in a `AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'dropna' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`

Comment: Use second solution, there is also `dropna`

Comment: I add solution for remove NaN.

Comment: In the apply function, when lambda x is being used, does 'x' correspond to the row elements? Can you share your knowledge about where apply and lambda x needs to be used?

Comment: Sure, give me a minute.

Comment: Lightning fast solutions! Couldn't have asked for more:)

Comment: apply(f), I believe this needs to be apply(f(x)) since x is an argument

Comment: It can be omit I think, try it by it can works also, but I am not sure.

Comment: I checked it, apply(f) works fine, but I am confused as to why apply(f(x)) doesn't work.

Comment: If you want pass argument, you can change `df = battles.groupby('attacker_king')['attacker_commander'].apply(f)` to `df = battles.groupby('attacker_king').apply(lambda x: f(x['attacker_commander']))`

Comment: Well I didnt notice its `battles.groupby('attacker_king')['attacker_commander']` that is input to apply() method, that means automatically each row is fed as input to f()

Comment: Exactly - you define it in `[]` - column which is pass to x.

Answer (score 1):

you want to join the strings by groups then split and find the unique values.

```
df.groupby(
    'attacker_king'
).attacker_commander.apply(','.join).str.split(',').apply(pd.unique)

attacker_king
Joffrey/Tommen Baratheon      [Jaime Lannister, Gregor Clegane,  Andros Brax]
Robb Stark                  [Roose Bolton,  Wylis Manderly,  Medger Cerwyn...
Name: attacker_commander, dtype: object
```